# Unable to pass array from service to component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to pass an array from service.ts to component . I want to show the array of elements in dialog box.
So I am getting Typescript error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'departmentArr' of undefined`.

I am unable to understand the error why departmentArr is undefined.

**In service:**

```js
private todos: Todo[] = [];
private db: any;
public departmentArr: any = [];
    
async searchDepartments(): Promise<Observable<any>> {
  const fetchData3 = await this.db.todos.orderBy('department').keys(function (departments) {
    alert("Departments are: " + departments.join(','));
    this.departmentArr.push(departments.join(','));
  });
  return this.departmentArr;
}
```

In Component I need to get array from `departmentArr`.

```js
connection: any;
async showTable() {
    this.connection = (await this.todoService.searchDepartments()).subscribe(message => {
    //here message is the array                     
    console.log(message);
    this.dialog.open(AppComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      autoFocus: true,
      data: message
    });
  });
}
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: can you console `departmentArr` in your service, to check what are you getting there?

Comment: can you specify whats inside the departmentArr

Comment: `Promise<Observable<any>>`. What?

Comment: @GauravGupta I am consoling after push method and I am not getting anything because of the typescript error thrown.

Comment: @RohithV I am pushing data querying from database to the empty array `departmentArr` ex: `['data', 'accounts']`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I tried with `Observable<departmentArr>` to which I am getting error as return type of async func/method must be global.

Comment: @NoobCoder, are you receiving anything from the DB (backend) ?

Comment: @GauravGupta yes I am , If I console `console.log(departments.join(','));` ,  I will get something like `['data', 'accounts']`

Comment: `departments.join(',')` should return a string I believe not an array ?

Comment: @GauravGupta you are right , it is string my mistake `data,gic,account`. So how can I push this string to an array ? If I declare an array inside the function and do push then it is something like `['data', 'accounts']`.  But why I am getting the typescript error here?

Comment: What does the this.db.todos method look like? What does it return?

Comment: @Tommi it returns strings `data,gic,account`. A query for database

Comment: @NoobCoder Do you mind edit the post and share what it looks like? Does it return the data as a promise or just as an array?

Comment: @Tommi If I do `console.log("Departments are: " + departments.join(','));` , it will console -  `data,gic,accounts,HR` like this. Not an array. I have gone through below solutions it is working well now but , I am facing an error on component part as `TypeError: (intermediate value).subscribe is not a function`

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn how `this` keyword works in JS.

You pass a callback function to keys, and you assume that `this` points to the instance of the enclosing class - which is not the case.

In [function context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context) in strict mode `this` evaluates to `undefined`

Typical solutions:

- Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#arrow_functions). In arrow functions, `this` retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's `this`
- Use helper variable outside the callback. It will be captured via callback's lexical context
- This can be modified by calling [the bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#the_bind_method)

Small example to visualise the concepts:

```ts
class MyClass {

public departmentArr: string[] = [];

 runCallback(fun: () => void) {
   fun();
 }

 searchDepartmentsFun() {
  this.runCallback(function() {
    console.log("In function: this: ", this);
  });
 }

 searchDepartmentsArrow() {
  this.runCallback(() => {
    console.log("In arrow function: this: ", this);
  });
 }

 searchDepartmentsCapture() {
  const capturedArr = this.departmentArr; 
  this.runCallback(function() {
    console.log("In fun with capture function: this: ", this, ' catpured arr: ', capturedArr);
  });
 }

 searchDepartmentsBind() {
  this.runCallback(function() {
    console.log("In bound fun with capture function: this: ", this);
  }.bind(this));
 }


}

const c = new MyClass();
c.searchDepartmentsFun();
c.searchDepartmentsArrow();
c.searchDepartmentsCapture();
c.searchDepartmentsBind();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&ts=4.3.5#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQGAOBXARiAJbDQAmAptmAE4AuAthQHZ0CCNNAXNBHTUWYBzANoBdaAF5o4gNxZoNXM0RgQIfGGABrABQAzZT10BKKQD5oANwD2RMmczRnh5qfnQAvgogVawAAsAESpaRhY6CAAxZVN0DGc6AKIIADolFTUNLT1XYDoiGzdHBOdoYCKIGxAKVJAbIV0AIgBJZmg8gqKeJJSeJoAaaF6IEw8vMYTvBN9-YND6JlYIDhobAHc4p2HktIzVdU0dXTjJS23nCuYqmrqG5rboWjX1juV8wuYe3f6hkcnnJ4AdNeH4aIEQtRFhEIKpsHRcDQKFtSlc%20OUwPDERQyKspDsUqlKFDwqxVrJoKURullAdssdOp8UWVypVqrV6o1Wu1XNB1kQkhisUi3swPt0CRBfpKhgByDF0PBIshPTg8WVDYCYhHK1YAiYeEGzcHzElLSIAIUEZGZkppmUOOQM7y6xXiLLR7LuXMe%20BsyhVvP5gq1wooovFX0l0v%20408qXw1t0-2BWAw0zRdHK%20OYFFeCGQkAg7gwwFSxohC1JkRixXkZYrprC5pWnA2JYbYMrZphcJ1yMmnbmkObMKtzBtYyAA)

On top of that, you may want to set `noImplicitThis` option, to rule out the possibility of `this` shadowing an outer value of 'this'.
As the solution with `bind` is flagged by this setting, this one is less frequent a solution in TS.

Comment: This is such a neat explanation. I got the use of  `this now`. Thanks. Even though in component it will throw `TypeError: (intermediate value).subscribe is not a function` if I remove async.

Comment: You subscribe to an Observable, not to a Promise. Does it work with async/await? I think it begs for another question to describe your expectations and desired behaviour.

Comment: Ah right ! I ended up modifying with another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472110/getting-an-empty-array-on-subscribing

Answer (score 1):

Here I have changed the `function` to an arrow function `() =>`

```
private todos: Todo[] = [];
private db: any;
public departmentArr: any = [];
    
async searchDepartments(): Promise<Observable<any>> {
  const fetchData3 = await this.db.todos.orderBy('department').keys( (departments) => {
    alert("Departments are: " + departments.join(','));
    this.departmentArr.push(departments.join(','));
  });
  return this.departmentArr;
}
```

or create a local variable in and assign `this. departmentArr` to it.

```
private todos: Todo[] = [];
private db: any;
public departmentArr: any = [];

async searchDepartments(): Promise<Observable<any>> {
 var tempArr = this.departmentArr;
  const fetchData3 = await this.db.todos.orderBy('department').keys( (departments) => {
    alert("Departments are: " + departments.join(','));
    tempArr.push(departments.join(','));
  });
  return tempArr;
}
```